# How to remove green bars at each end of line?

Tags: intellij-idea

I work on IntelliJ, and I would like to remove the green bar which appeared at the end of each line, for a reason I can't identify. Any idea ?

[image: A screenshot of the green bars]

Comment: Try to [disable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) all third-party plugins.

Comment: Also, try to reset color scheme settings under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | click on gear icon | Restore Defaults`